# How to keep video on html5 playing when clicked on video element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, video, html5-video

im trying to create simple video conference and i want to produce only fullscreen feature on screen sharing video element, and i want to disabled all other controls like **volume, mute, seek, play, pause and pictures in pictures**.

i already success to hide (volume, mute, seek, play, pause and pictures in pictures) *[not sure if theres a way to disabled that features]* and only available fullscreen button.

and im create simple `eventlistener` to keep video playing when i clicked on video element and prevent from pause.

```
videoScreen.addEventListener('click', () => {
   videoScreen.play()
})
```

but when i click on video element, my video going to freeze.

here's my code to create video element

```
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('videoShareScreen')

const screenOwner = document.createElement('span')
screenOwner.innerHTML = `${this.shareScreen.userName}'s Screen`
videoGrid.appendChild(screenOwner)
        
const videoScreen = document.createElement('video')
videoScreen.className = `screen-video screen-${this.shareScreen.userID}`
videoScreen.srcObject = this.shareScreen.stream
videoScreen.muted = true
videoScreen.controls = true
videoScreen.disablePictureInPicture = true
videoScreen.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    videoScreen.play()
})
videoScreen.addEventListener('click', () => {
    videoScreen.play()
})
videoGrid.appendChild(videoScreen)
```

FYI: im using `vueJS`

Comment: Where are your semicolons?

Comment: im rarely using `semicolon` when writing `javascript` program, i think in my case `semicolon` is not the problem..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to disable `controls` and then add some image (icon) or text that can be clicked to go into fullscreen.
You cannot avoid auto-pause when clicking the video if you have used:

```
"videoScreen.controls = true".
```

You'll have to use

```
videoScreen.setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction()" ); //vueJS is.. videoScreen.onclick = myFunction() ..?
```

or

```
videoScreen.addEventListener("click", myFunction );
```

where `myFunction` looks like (example) :

```
function myFunction() 
{
    videoScreen.play();
    alert("you clicked on video");
}
```

Here is some basic HTML5 code to test and then apply similar logic to your Vue JS project:

```
<html>
<body>

<video id="myVid" width="500" height="400">
<source src="somefile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>

var videoScreen = document.getElementById('myVid');

videoScreen.addEventListener("click", myFunction );

function myFunction() 
{
    videoScreen.play();
    alert("you clicked on video");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```